# Windows: Not showing a shared folder with no-access

Tags: windows, permissions, shared-folders

A network shared folder `KAISHA` contains a bunch of folders

- Accounting
- IT
- Management
- etc...

The shared folder is hosted by a Linux / Samba4 machine, that serves Active Directory as well.
Clients are Windows 7+.
All of that works fine.

However, only accounting people have access to `Accounting`, only IT people have access to `IT` etc...

But, everyone sees all the below folders when connecting to `KAISHA`, even though they may not have an access inside.
It would be better to see only the folders to which one has access.

**Question**: is there a setting in Active Directory / Folder sharing / Folder permissions to only show a folder to people having at least *Read* access to it?

Comment: You may be able to grant "Traverse Folder" on "KAISHA" but not "List Folder". This should make it so they can't see the directories, though they likely won't be able to see their own directory either (they must know the name to get to it).

Comment: This is called Access-based Enumeration, by the way.

Comment: @Ringo . . . You say `only accounting people have access to Accounting, only IT people have access to IT etc...` based on these words, there will NEVER be an instance where some one person will need access to more than one directory beneath this `KAISHA` share. If that is the case, then you can have these people's mapped drives map to the applicable departmental subfolder rather than the share. If there are cases where that's cross departmental for some, then that may not work. Not sure how you're mapping the drives on the Windows PCs like login script, group policy preferences, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the `smb.conf` file the following.

**To hide inaccessible files/folders :**

```
hide unreadable = yes
```

**To hide non-writable files/folders :**

```
hide unwriteable files = yes
```

Restart Samba for this to take effect.

Comment: Using this but how do we have Samba update the list of files when we change permissions to a folder or add users to a group so they now have access to a folder. Anyway to do this without restarting samba?